# Word: Use different styles for endnotes and footnotes

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I have a Word document containing both footnotes and endnotes.  How do I change the numbering format for one or the other of those reference note types?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `References` menu and click on the little pop-out box in the lower right of the `Footnotes` section of that menu.  This will open a "Footnote and Endnote" dialog box.  Click on the desired type under `Location` and then change the `Number format`, as in the screenshot here:

[image: Menu path to change number format of footnotes and endnotes in Word]